# Monitor can toggle between two HDMI inputs, the inactive input still thinks it is active as long as HDMI cable is connected

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I recently purchased a new monitor (an Acer - Nitro XF243Y). It has two HDMI inputs. It is primarily used with my Windows desktop computer. I occassionally want to use it as a second screen for my Macbook Pro M1 laptop. There is a button on the monitor to toggle between the two HDMI inputs. The problem occurs when I want to use the monitor for the Windows desktop, but also use the laptop separately. If the Windows desktop is the selected HDMI input for the monitor, but the Macbook is still also plugged in to the other HDMI input, the Macbook still "thinks" it has an external display connected, and most of the open windows are not accessible on the laptop's built-in display. The only way I've found to get the laptop to work properly in this situation is to pull out the HDMI cable. Is there any way for the monitor to communicate to the inactive HDMI connection that it is inactive? It seems like it would be better if I wasn't frequently pulling out and putting back the HDMI cable.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of by design.
If the display were to pretend it was no longer there, everything would fall back to the primary display, meaning you'd have to put it all back again next time it was connected. This paradigm has generally been messed up since everybody switched to laptops plus an external display. Basically, whichever paradigm is used, *you can't win 'em all*.

Best I could suggest is see if the display manufacturer has included some kind of switching between behaviours in their hardware setup [don't hold your breath].

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! That makes sense. Although, before I had this new monitor, my previous monitor had only one HDMI input and I used an HDMI Switch product to connect the two computers. With that product, pressing the button to switch inputs to the desktop does cause the laptop to think the monitor is no longer there. I was hoping the two HDMI inputs in the new monitor would work the same way. Regarding "some kind of switching between behaviours" ... any idea what that would look like? E.g. what it might be called in the settings?

Comment: I honestly don't expect there to be a software switch… sorry ;)  Your old KVM switcher was actually behaving poorly, they shouldn't break the connection - it just resulted accidentally in behaviour you preferred.